# Angular 6 ngrx, how to add new item to array in state object?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a simple situation, I have actions Like CreatUser, CreateSuccess, CreateFail. How should I add new object to array and when `Create` action is dispatched or `CreateSuccess`? And how should I do that?

```
export function reducer(state = init, action: Actions): State {
switch (action.type) {
    case ActionsTypes.CREATE:
        return {
            ...state,
            inProgress: true
        };
    case ActionsTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: state.users.push(action.payload),
            inProgress: false
        };
    case ActionsTypes.CREATE_FAIL:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload,
            inProgress: false
        };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

In code above I tried to add new user using push method, but it is not good solution. How should I do that?

Answer (score 40):

Try to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) because it creates a new array of users and does not mutate the previous array.

```
users: [...state.users, action.payload]
```

Or else use [@ngrx/entity](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/entity/README.md) module for arrays. It's the best way.

**Update 13.07.2019**

New module [@ngrx/data](https://ngrx.io/guide/data) is available in NgRx 8. This module helps to create CRUD store for arrays with zero boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect answer. Could you also show me how to update one User?

Comment: In you reducer you need to findIndex of updated user, create new users array with spred operator, replace updated user and return new array. If you user @ngrx/entity or ngrx-data. You can use updateOne method.

Comment: Do you recommend using ngrx entity?

Comment: Yes its best way for arrays. Or try to use [angular-ngrx-data](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data). its simplest then @ngrx/entity

Comment: spread operation for big arrays could be a problem

Answer (score 9):

Your state should be immutable therefore would be better to use

```
users: state.users.concat(action.payload)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is for those who is searching how to add item at the begining of the array in an immutable manner unlike using unshift operator which mutates the original.
Placing new item at the begining of operation makes the magic

`users: [action.payload,...state.users]`

Comment: that would be a bad idea for big arrays... this spread creates new array and copies the data into it..

Answer (score 6):

```js
export const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(addTodo, (state, { todo }) => ({
    ...state,
    todoInput: '',
    todos: [...state.todos, todo]
  }))
);
```

See: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks